# track, rail in Italian

Tags: vocabulary

What would you call track and rail in Italian? Track is the whole thing while rail is a piece of metal e.g. on the right.

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zL5aEWRzgSt719K4V_TSOdIN49ZTdyGHEB0B0ZX5un-iDIEyJfQ-m0JqhW1f4ytN2Iw=w300]

Is it binario for both?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the word *rotaia* to refer to the single piece

from *Wikipedia* (page *Binario ferroviario*):

> Il binario ferroviario è l'infrastruttura basilare nella costruzione di linee ferroviarie e tranviarie. Esso è una struttura composta da due profilati metallici in acciaio, detti rotaie...

*Binario* is referred to the whole track instead. In stations, *binario* also means "platform"

One more curious thing: you can use *rotaie* to refer to railroads in general (but *ferrovie* is more common).

Comment: So "track" would be "binario" and "rail" would be "rotaia"? Could you please clarify that in your answer?

Comment: Fixed it, also added another detail about _binario_

Comment: Another curious thing: when you use "rotaie" to refer to "ferrovie" you are using a _sineddoche_.

Comment: 'synecdoche' in inglese